# What is happening in this WinMain() declaration?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am learning about C++ and programming to the windows api. My first "Hello Windows API" program just displays a MessageBox(). But, I have questions that the book I'm reading isn't explaining.

First, here's the program:

```
// HelloWin32 Program
#include<Windows.h>
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "This gets displayed in the message.", "This is the title bar of the message dialog.", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
}
```

This compiles and runs fine. My question has to do with the WinMain() declaration that says `int WINAPI WinMain(...)`. As I read it, the WinMain function (method?) returns an integer. But what does `WINAPI` communicate?

Obviously, I'm writing to the Windows API. Does `WINAPI` somehow flag the function so the program uses Windows API to execute it or something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`WINAPI` is a preprocessor definition defined as `__stdcall`, a calling convention; when functions have `__stdcall` before their name, it is a directive to the compiler to make the function use that calling convention. This is so both your function and the function calling your function agree to use the stdcall calling convention and the call executes correctly.

This is necessary because the default calling convention of your compiler may or may not be stdcall, so you have to explicitly tell the compiler to make it that way for that function. The designers of the Windows API decided, mainly for compatibility reasons and the universality of the stdcall calling convention, to make all function calls use the stdcall calling convention.

Also, you can have functions with different calling conventions being used in the same program. So for instance, `WinMain` has to be stdcall but the other functions of your program do not; they can use the compiler default.

A **calling convention** is a method for doing things like the order in which parameters should go on the stack, who should remove them from the stack when the function returns, where to put return values, and other things. Different calling conventions do this in different ways. Above all, it is extremely important that *both the caller and the callee follow the same calling convention*. For more info on calling conventions, see [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention).

Comment: Is it important for me to understand different calling conventions? I've never come across them before (I started with C#.)

Comment: @quakkels it is very good but not absolutely necessary to know. If you ever delve into the generated assembly of a C++ program it will be necessary to know about calling conventions, but otherwise it can be viewed as an implementation detail (hidden behind the `WINAPI` preprocessor definition). Probably (though I don't have evidence) many C++ programmers write fine programs without knowing anything about calling conventions. Knowing more about how things work underneath is never a bad thing though :)

Comment: Without the `WINAPI` I get this error:
`warning C4007: 'WinMain': must be '__stdcall'`
Your answer helped me understand why